# SOLVED - add_action() for $product->get_date_created

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a code that set "new" tag for products. I want to set that tag for products that have less than 14 days. I used for call the function `add_action('init', 'name_fct');`, but I get an error, I tried with `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'name_fct');`, but doesn't work. Please help me to develop my code to work. My code is:
**SOLVED THANK YOU JACOB**

```
function display_new_loop_woocommerce() {
global $product;
global $datetime_created;
global $timestamp_created;
global $datetime_now;
global $timestamp_now;

$datetime_now = new WC_DateTime();
$timestamp_now = $datetime_now->getTimestamp();


$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product', // your product post type
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
);

$posts = get_posts($args);

foreach ($posts as $post):
    setup_postdata($post);
    
    $product = new WC_Product($post->ID);
    
    $datetime_created = $product->get_date_created();
    $timestamp_created = $datetime_created->getTimestamp();
    
    $time_delta = $timestamp_now - $timestamp_created; 
    $sixty_days = 14 * 24 * 60 * 60; 
    

    if ( $time_delta < $sixty_days ) {
        if( ! has_term( '', 'product_tag', $post->ID ) ) :
            wp_set_object_terms($post->ID, array('nou'), 'product_tag');
        endif;   
    } else {
        if( has_term( '', 'product_tag', $post->ID ) ) :
            wp_remove_object_terms($post->ID, array('nou'), 'product_tag');
        endif;   
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
endforeach;
}
```

Comment: This is going to write to your database for every single product on every page load. You are going to absolutely ruin your site's performance, if it's even able to run at all. This is completely the wrong approach, even if it were implemented correctly, which it's not.

Comment: Maybe if I call this function once per day? I saw a lot of websites that have new badge for new products. But I don't know why $post->get_date_created(); broke my website. What is wrong?

Comment: Because you're calling it on `global $product;` which doesn't exist.

Comment: But if Am I calling it on $post? into the foreach loop? I modify my first post, but it doesn't work even if I used into the loop...

Comment: `WP_Post` doesn't have a `get_date_created()` method. It needs to be an instance of `WC_Product`. You can turn a post into a product with `wc_get_product()`, but it's not going to solve the problem of writing massive amounts of data to the database on every page load.

Comment: Thank you Jacob for your time. If I will call that function once per day? It will solve writing massive amounts of data on every page load?